# What are our options when no appointments are available at Schengen visa center?

Tags: schengen, italy, schengen-visas

I am trying to get a Schengen visa for my trip to Italy in September at the Italian Consulate in Miami. Unfortunately, there are no appointments for next three months!

Is there any hope at all of getting a visa in this time frame? I still have nearly 7 weeks before my trip, but we are already talking about cancellations etc., because of no visa appointments. Any strategies that would work?

There is a waiting list for the Italian Consulate Miami, but I am not sure how reliable it is going to be.

Comment: That's crazy.  It is not allowed to apply more than three months "before the start of the intended visit."  They really need to get their act together.

Comment: @phoog Worst part is, they absolutely wont care! However you can take an appointment as long as it is within 3 months of travel, which really means I had to plan 6 months ahead of time, which is practical nightmare.

Comment: Maybe travel to another country and go from there. You might be able to get appointments in the new countries consulate.

Comment: @edocetirwi Thats easier said than done! We had planned our itinerary for 6 months carefully researching every think we do. Hard to think about screwing it all up for stupid visa appointments issue. In all five months of planning, it never occurred that 2 months is not enough for visa.